# Saving instance values in a javascript class using the prototype pattern

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'll admit I'm flailing around, cobbling code together from different authors in an attempt to figure out javascript prototypes.

I'm new to the prototype concept, and would like to have some instance variables in my class that can be modified using a method.

Here's what I'm trying, in essence.  This was cribbed and modified from the web:

```
var MyGlobe = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.variable1 = null;
    return self;
}

MyGlobe.prototype = function () {
    var setup = function () {
        this.variable1 = 33;
    };
     return {
        setup:setup
    };
 }();
```

...the point of all that is so I can call the `setup` method on an instance of `MyGlobe` and set `variable1` properly:

```
var aGlobe = new MyGlobe();
aGlobe.setup();

//aGlobe.variable1 is 33 now
```

This actually seems to work, but I'm not sure why the original author did things this way?  For instance, what's the point of the `self.variable1` bit at the beginning?

Is it preferable to typing out:

```
MyGlobe.prototype.variable1;
MyGlobe.prototype.variable2;
//....
```

I also thought you'd do something like `self=this` if you thought your class would be used in a callback function for example, but that doesn't appear to be the case here? (Happy to be shown wrong.)

I'm not sure what the best practices are here and would like to know more.

Comment: Yes, there's a lot of really unnecessary stuff around this code. Either it made sense before it was modified, or you should not use it like this :-)

Comment: "*Is it preferable to typing out `MyGlobe.prototype.variable1;`*" - What exactly? If you're referring to `self.variable1`, they're not the same.

Comment: What I mean by 'is it preferable to typing out...'-- is it better to declare the instance variables in the constructor function (`self.variable1`) as opposed to adding them to the prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This actually seems to work, but I'm not sure why the original author did things this way? For instance, what's the point of the self.variable1 bit at the beginning?

None (for using `self`), the "declaration of instance properties" (even if only initialising them to `null`) can help engines to use more memory-efficient internal structures - though it's not really necessary.

> I also thought you'd do something like self=this if you thought your class would be used in a callback function for example, but that doesn't appear to be the case here?

Exactly. This small snippet really should be rewritten to

```
var MyGlobe = function () {
    this.variable1 = null;
}
MyGlobe.prototype.setup = function() {
    this.variable1 = 33;
};
```

> Is it better to declare the instance variables in the constructor function (`self.variable1`) as opposed to adding them to the prototype (`MyGlobe.prototype.variable1`)?

That's simple. On the prototype it's no *instance* property any more. And please distinguish between *variables* (like `self` - which are local-scoped to the function) and *properties* (like `prototype`, `setup` or `variable1` - which are "public" on the object).